# Error: Cannot find module './lodash'

Tags: node.js, lodash

Already searched for it - but can't find anything. When i start my script, i get this error. Already installed Lodash, cleared cache and reinstalled node.

```
module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './lodash'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\**\node_modules\steam-tradeoffers\node_modules\cheerio\node_modules\lodash\index.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests that you're looking for an internal module by requiring a local path `./lodash` try `require('lodash')` instead.